# Pass Additional Arguments to Pandas Custom Accessor

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a custom accessor class for a Pandas Dataframe - I have followed the examples here and achieved positive results. However I have a function where I would like to pass additional arguments.

I have created this function within my accessor class:

```
    @property
    def accessor_function(self, time_window=0.5):
        def group_function(df, time):
            fl = df.loc[df.Type_num==0]
            id = fl.Time.idxmin() 
            threshold = df.loc[id, 'column'] + time
        return fl.loc[fl.Time<threshold]

    self.Subset = self._obj.groupby(by['col_1','col_2']).apply(group_function, time_window)
    self.Subset.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    return self.Subset
```

If I call this like this it works using `time_window=0.5`:

```
df.accessor.accessor_function
```

However if I want to pass a different value for the keyword argument:

```
df.accessor.accessor_function(time_window = 1)
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

I can't find any obvious documentation explaining passing `args` or `kwargs` to custom accessors. So I'm not sure if what I'm attempting is even possible. But it would be good to understand how to move forward.

Ben

Answer (score 5):

I believe it has to do with the fact that you are using the `porperty` decorator when actually you have a method. If you remove that, it should work fine, see example below:

```py
import pandas as pd
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("accessor")
class MyAccessor:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        self._obj = pandas_obj

    def accessor_function(self, time_window=0.5):
        def group_function(df, time):
            fl = df.loc[df.Type_num==0]
            id = fl.Time.idxmin() 
            threshold = df.loc[id, 'column'] + time
            return fl.loc[fl.Time<threshold]

        self.Subset = self._obj.groupby(['col_1','col_2']).apply(group_function, time_window)
        self.Subset.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

        return self.Subset
```

The default case is:

```
>>> a = pd.DataFrame({'Type_num': [False, False,False,False,False], 
                      'Time': [1, 2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5],
                      'col_1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
                      'col_2': ['A', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'E'],
                      'column': [0.2, 0.2,0.2, 0.2,0.2]})
>>> a.accessor.accessor_function()
   Type_num  Time col_1 col_2  column
0     False   0.1     C     C     0.2
1     False   0.2     D     E     0.2
2     False   0.5     E     E     0.2
```

You can use a custom `time_window`

```
>>> a.accessor.accessor_function(time_window=1)
   Type_num  Time col_1 col_2  column
0     False   1.0     A     A     0.2
1     False   0.1     C     C     0.2
2     False   0.2     D     E     0.2
3     False   0.5     E     E     0.2
```

Or pass that parameter using `*arg` or `**kwargs`:

```
>>> a.accessor.accessor_function(*[2])
   Type_num  Time col_1 col_2  column
0     False   1.0     A     A     0.2
1     False   2.0     B     A     0.2
2     False   0.1     C     C     0.2
3     False   0.2     D     E     0.2
4     False   0.5     E     E     0.2

>>> a.accessor.accessor_function(**{'time_window':0.1})
   Type_num  Time col_1 col_2  column
0     False   0.1     C     C     0.2
1     False   0.2     D     E     0.2
```